# Programmatically check if iPhone clock is synched

Tags: objective-c, datetime, time, synchronization

Is there anyway to check if the iPhone clock is internet synched or if it is manually set from my program? I need to verify if the user is changing the clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but my impression is that the iPhone will sync it's clock any time it gets a cellular signal, so perhaps checking for the presence of a cellular network would be "close enough."

Perhaps it would be even more straightforward to just call out to a trusted NTP server on the Internet and see what the skew is between the system clock and the trusted server.